# Avoid duplicate rows, without reference to keys or indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table in which each row is a TV episode. It looks like this:

```
     showTitle  |  season   |  episode   |  episodeTitle  |  airdate  |  absoluteEpisode
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 The X-Files          5          12          Bad Blood     1998-02-22         109
 The X-Files          5          13          Patient X     1998-03-01         110
```

(Where `absoluteEpisode` is the episode's overall number counting from episode 1.)

It is populated using a Ruby program I wrote which fetches the data from a web service. Periodically, I'd like to run the program again to fetch new episodes. The question then becomes, how do I avoid adding duplicates of the already-existing rows? None of the columns in this table are suitable for use as a primary key or unique field.

I had two ideas. The first was to create a new column, `md5`, with an MD5 hash of all of those values, and make that a unique column, to prevent two rows with identical data from being added. That seems like it would work, but be messy.

My second was to use [this solution from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159663/how-to-use-on-duplicate-key-update-in-mysql-without-a-unique-index-or-primary-ke). But I can't quite get that to work. My SQL query is

```
INSERT INTO `tv`.`episodes` (showTitle,episodeTitle,season,episode,date,absoluteEpisode) 
SELECT '#{show}','#{title}','#{y['airdate']}' FROM `tv`.`episodes`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from `tv`.`episodes` 
WHERE showTitle='#{show}' AND episodeTitle='#{title}' AND season='#{season_string}' AND episode='#{y['seasonnum']}' AND date='#{y['airdate']}' AND absoluteEpisode='#{y['epnum']}'")
```

The `#{...}` bits are Ruby variables. This gets me the obvious error `You have an error in your SQL syntax`.

Flipping through the books and documentation I can find on the subject, I'm still not sure how to properly execute this query, or if it's not a smart way of solving my problem. I'd appreciate any advice!

Comment: what is the full error message post in your question

Comment: Instead of using an `md5` of all relevant values, you can also add a single unique index on a combination of all those fields.

Comment: Maybe [how to create a composite key in MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15302011/205233) could help.

Comment: `(showTitle, season, episode)` looks like it could be used as primary or unique key. `(showTitle, absoluteEpisode)` as well.

Answer (score 0):

why not create a primary key from the `showTitle`, season, and episode, this will solve the problem because I guess because the episode number can not be duplicate under the same season, and that's apply for the same TV show,
 example

x-files==>season 1==>episode 1 this will be primary key as one unit